# How to send data from Raspberry pi to Remote SQL DB without installing mysql or mysql Client

Tags: shell-script, raspberry-pi, mysql, tcp

I would like send some port checking data and a timestamp ( both saved as a variable) to my remote Mysql DB running on a linux Node machine . I don't want install sql or sql client in Pi because the device having  enough load already

Comment: You seem to have previously asked a question about transferring files to a remote server. Using the same approach, you could collect your data into a local file first, and then send it across.

Comment: maybe rsyslog with MySQL? see https://opensourceforu.com/2015/10/remote-logging-using-rsyslog-and-mysql/

Comment: Can you ssh from the pi to the database server?

Comment: If you just want to insert the data into MySQL on your server then you can just install `mysql-community-client` on your Raspberry Pi. It won't use many resources. That will just provide the `mysql` command which you can use to connect the `mysql` on your server after you've allowed remote connections. Another way is to install `phpmyadmin` on the server and use the web interface to enter data. You can also `ssh` into the server and input the data that way as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you can `ssh` to the database server, you can run `mysql` directly on the server via `ssh`:

```
ssh user@dbserver \
  mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD \
    -e "insert into table (data, timestamp) VALUES ('${data}','${timestamp}') " \
    database-name
```